# Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined at Tab._activate (bootstrap.js:3687)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multi step form that has "Next" and "Go back" buttons in each step. But every time a "Next" or "GO back" button is clicked on  the console appears:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined at Tab._activate (bootstrap.js:3687)`

Do you know what can be the issue? I have a fiddle with the example but in the fiddle the buttons no navigate between the form steps are not working dont know why.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7r1tg863/4/

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li class="">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
      Step 1<br>
      <small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">General Info</small>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="disabled">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
      Step 2<br>
      <small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">Organizer</small>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="disabled">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
      Passo 3<br>
      <small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">Registration Types</small>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="disabled">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#step4" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
      Step 4<br>
      <small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">Other configs</small>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>

<form method="post" class="clearfix" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="tab-content registration_body bg-white" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel"
         aria-labelledby="home-tab">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Title
        </label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" value=""
               name="name" id="name">
      </div>

      <div class="float-right">
        <button type="button" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn next-step">
          Next
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="step2" role="tabpanel"
         aria-labelledby="profile-tab">


      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="organizer_name" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Name
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value=""
                 value="" required name="organizer_name"
                 id="organizer_name" placeholder="Nome do Organizador">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="organizer_email" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Email
          </label>
          <input type="email" required name="organizer_email"
                 value="" class="form-control"
                 id="organizer_email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="organizer_description"
               class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Description</label>
        <textarea name="organizer_description" id="organizer_description"
                  value="" class="form-control"
                  rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>


      <button type="button" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
              class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-primary btn prev-step">
        go back to step 1
      </button>
      <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
              class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn next-step">
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="step3" role="tabpanel"
         aria-labelledby="contact-tab">

      <span>step 3</span>

      <button type="button" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
              class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-primary btn prev-step">
        Go bak to step 2
      </button>
      <button type="button" href="#step4" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
              class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn next-step">
        Next
      </button>


    </div>


    <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="step4" role="tabpanel"
         aria-labelledby="contact-tab">

      <span>tab 4</span>


      <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
              class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-primary btn prev-step">
        Go back to step 3
      </button>

      <button type="submit" formaction=""
              class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-primary btn next-step">
        Store and Publish
      </button>

      <button type="submit" formaction=""
              class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn next-step">
        Store
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello @John May be you have to use "live" jquery event handling. I am not sure but may be this will work in your case - Reference - http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks, can you explain better?

Comment: Were is the PHP in this?